# I want to understand how streams work with bloc pattern in flutter?

Tags: flutter, stream, bloc

What does `emit.forEach()` do? From what I understand, it takes a stream but how does the ui rebuild itself and what is the `onData` parameter? I want to return a stream of data for a client matrix sdk

```
  on<StartMatrixEventSubmitted>((event, emit) async {
      emit(MatrixLoadingState());
      await repo.getAllRooms().then((value) async {
        await emit.forEach(
          value.onSync.stream,
          onData: (value2) {
            print('data');
            return MatrixSuccuClientState(rooms: value.rooms);
          },
        );
        this.myRooms = value.rooms;
        emit(MatrixClientSynced());
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the description of what `emit.forEach` does in the [docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/bloc/latest/bloc/Emitter/forEach.html):

> Subscribes to the provided stream and invokes the onData callback when
> the stream emits new data and the result of onData is emitted.

Basically, it's the same as a List's `.map()` method. Each and every data (element) in the list will be converted into another value. Eg: Object to String

`emit.forEach` takes two values: the stream it has to listen to and the `onData` function. It will listen to all of the values emitted by the stream and convert them into another value (In this case `MatrixSuccuClientState`).
Think of `value2` in `onData: (value2)` as the *"`element[index]` in a list"*. The `value2` is the currently emitted value of the stream. I think what you're looking for is:

`onData: (currentlyEmittedValue) => MatrixSuccuClientState(rooms: currentlyEmittedValue.rooms),`

I'd suggest understanding `Streams` in flutter before moving on to bloc. I suggest watching this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nQBpOIHE4eE). After that, you could learn how bloc works in this [dev page](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/gettingstarted)